# reshape wide to long with character suffixes instead of numeric suffixes

Tags: r, reshape

Inspired by [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161807/reshape-in-the-middle/10170630#comment13051721_10170630) from @gsk3 on a question about reshaping data, I started doing a little bit of experimentation with reshaping data where the variable names have character suffixes instead of numeric suffixes.

As an example, I'll load the `dadmomw` dataset from one of the [UCLA ATS Stata learning webpages](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/modules/reshaping-data-wide-to-long/) (see "Example 4" on the webpage).

Here's what the dataset looks like:

```
library(foreign)
dadmom <- read.dta("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/stata/modules/dadmomw.dat")
dadmom
#   famid named  incd namem  incm
# 1     1  Bill 30000  Bess 15000
# 2     2   Art 22000   Amy 18000
# 3     3  Paul 25000   Pat 50000
```

When trying to reshape from this wide format to long, I run into a problem. Here's what I do to reshape the data.

```
reshape(dadmom, direction="long", idvar=1, varying=2:5, 
        sep="", v.names=c("name", "inc"), timevar="dadmom",
        times=c("d", "m"))
#     famid dadmom  name  inc
# 1.d     1      d 30000 Bill
# 2.d     2      d 22000  Art
# 3.d     3      d 25000 Paul
# 1.m     1      m 15000 Bess
# 2.m     2      m 18000  Amy
# 3.m     3      m 50000  Pat
```

Note the swapped column names for "name" and "inc"; changing `v.names` to `c("inc", "name")` doesn't solve the problem.

`reshape` seems very picky about wanting the columns to be named in a fairly standard way. For example, I can reshape the data correctly (and easily) if I first rename the columns:

```
dadmom2 <- dadmom # Just so we can continue experimenting with the original data
# Change the names of the last four variables to include a "."
names(dadmom2)[2:5] <- gsub("(d$|m$)", "\\.\\1", names(dadmom2)[2:5])
reshape(dadmom2, direction="long", idvar=1, varying=2:5, 
        timevar="dadmom")
#     famid dadmom name   inc
# 1.d     1      d Bill 30000
# 2.d     2      d  Art 22000
# 3.d     3      d Paul 25000
# 1.m     1      m Bess 15000
# 2.m     2      m  Amy 18000
# 3.m     3      m  Pat 50000
```

My questions are:

1. Why is R swapping the columns in the example I've provided?
2. Can I get to this result with base R `reshape` without changing the variable names before reshaping?
3. Are there other approaches that could be considered instead of `reshape`?

Comment: The only evident reason for a Stata tag is that the example dataset is  in proprietary Stata format. That seems incidental, so I removed it. Feel free to reintroduce it if I missed something important.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works (to specify to varying what columns go with who):

```
reshape(dadmom, direction="long",  varying=list(c(2, 4), c(3, 5)), 
        sep="", v.names=c("name", "inc"), timevar="dadmom",
        times=c("d", "m"))
```

So you actually have nested repeated measures here; both name and inc for mom and dad.  Because you have more than one series of repeated measures you have to supply a `list` to varying that tells `reshape` which group gets stacked on the other group.

So the two approaches to this problem are to provide a list as I did or to rename the columns the way the R beast likes them as you did.

See my recent blogs on base `reshape` for more on this (particularly the second link deals with this):

[reshape (part I)](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/reshape-from-base-explained-part-i/)

[reshape (part II)](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/reshape-from-base-explained-part-ii/)

Comment: @DWin, I think the help page could also be re-written for clarity. Only after reading Tyler's solution and revisiting the page did I catch the line *This is canonically a list of vectors of variable names, but it can optionally be a matrix of names, or a single vector of names.* This is one of those functions that I regularly have the help page open for when I use it.

Comment: @mrdwab even after you point out the reshape help page explanation my little noodle still has a difficult time comprehending it.  It's such a large powerful function that it's difficult to describe all it does.  I tried to capture how it works in a pretty accessible language.  I hope it helps others.

Comment: @TylerRinker, you might be interested in some of the other approaches I've posted as alternatives to this answer. Of course, the check mark is still yours because it fully addressed my question, but I thought an update was required now that new tools have emerged.

Comment: Feel free to move it to guide future searchers.  +1 for the updating work.

Answer (score 8):

Though this question was specifically about base R, it is useful to know other approaches that help you to achieve the same type of outcome.

One alternative to `reshape` or `merged.stack` would be to use a combination of "dplyr" and "tidry", like this:

```
dadmom %>%
  gather(variable, value, -famid) %>%               ## Make the entire dataset long
  separate(variable, into = c("var", "time"),       ## Split "variable" column into two...
           sep = "(?<=name|inc)", perl = TRUE) %>%  ## ... using regex to split the values
  spread(var, value, convert = TRUE)                ## Make result wide, converting type
#   famid time   inc name
# 1     1    d 30000 Bill
# 2     1    m 15000 Bess
# 3     2    d 22000  Art
# 4     2    m 18000  Amy
# 5     3    d 25000 Paul
# 6     3    m 50000  Pat
```

Another alternative would be to use `melt` from "data.table", like this:

```
library(data.table)
melt(as.data.table(dadmom),             ## melt here requres a data.table 
     measure = patterns("name", "inc"), ## identify columns by patterns
     value.name = c("name", "inc"))[    ## specify the resulting variable names
       ## melt creates a numeric "variable" value. Replace with factored labels
       , variable := factor(variable, labels = c("d", "m"))][]
#    famid variable name   inc
# 1:     1        d Bill 30000
# 2:     2        d  Art 22000
# 3:     3        d Paul 25000
# 4:     1        m Bess 15000
# 5:     2        m  Amy 18000
# 6:     3        m  Pat 50000
```

How do these approaches compare with `merged.stack`?

- Both packages are much better supported. They update and test their code more extensively than I do.
- `melt` is blazing fast.
- The Hadleyverse approach is actually slower (in many of my tests, even slower than base R's `reshape`) probably because of having to make the data long, then wide, then performing type conversion. However, some users like its step-by-step approach.
- The Hadleyverse approach might have some unintended consequences because of the requirement of making the data long before making it wide. That forces all of the measure columns to be coerced to the same type (usually "character") if they are of different types to begin with.
- Neither have the same convenience of `merged.stack`. Just look at the code required to get the result ;-)

`merged.stack`, however, can probably benefit from a simplified update, something along the lines of [this function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/ceded54b616bdc61cb0f)

```
ReshapeLong_ <- function(indt, stubs, sep = NULL) {
  if (!is.data.table(indt)) indt <- as.data.table(indt)
  mv <- lapply(stubs, function(y) grep(sprintf("^%s", y), names(indt)))
  levs <- unique(gsub(paste(stubs, collapse="|"), "", names(indt)[unlist(mv)]))
  if (!is.null(sep)) levs <- gsub(sprintf("^%s", sep), "", levs, fixed = TRUE)
  melt(indt, measure = mv, value.name = stubs)[
    , variable := factor(variable, labels = levs)][]
}
```

Which can then be used as:

```
ReshapeLong_(dadmom, stubs = c("name", "inc"))
```

---

How do these approaches compare with base R's `reshape`?

- The main difference is that `reshape` is not able to handle unbalanced panel datasets. See, for example, "mydf2" as opposed to "mydf" in the tests below.

---

#### Test cases

Here's some sample data. "mydf" is balanced. "mydf2" is not balanced.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- 10000
mydf <- mydf2 <- data.frame(
  id_1 = 1:x, id_2 = c("A", "B"), varAa = sample(letters, x, TRUE), 
  varAb = sample(letters, x, TRUE), varAc = sample(letters, x, TRUE),
  varBa = sample(10, x, TRUE), varBb = sample(10, x, TRUE), 
  varBc = sample(10, x, TRUE), varCa = rnorm(x), varCb = rnorm(x), 
  varCc = rnorm(x), varDa = rnorm(x), varDb = rnorm(x), varDc = rnorm(x))

mydf2 <- mydf2[-c(9, 14)] ## Make data unbalanced
```

Here are some functions to test:

```
f1 <- function(mydf) {
  mydf %>%
    gather(variable, value, starts_with("var")) %>%
    separate(variable, into = c("var", "time"),
             sep = "(?<=varA|varB|varC|varD)", perl = TRUE) %>%
    spread(var, value, convert = TRUE) 
}

f2 <- function(mydf) {
  melt(as.data.table(mydf),
       measure = patterns(paste0("var", c("A", "B", "C", "D"))),
       value.name = paste0("var", c("A", "B", "C", "D")))[
         , variable := factor(variable, labels = c("a", "b", "c"))][]
}

f3 <- function(mydf) {
  merged.stack(mydf, var.stubs = paste0("var", c("A", "B", "C", "D")), sep = "var.stubs")
}

## Won't run with "mydf2". Should run with "mydf"
f4 <- function(mydf) {
  reshape(mydf, direction = "long", 
          varying = lapply(c("varA", "varB", "varC", "varD"), 
                           function(x) grep(x, names(mydf))), 
          sep = "", v.names = paste0("var", c("A", "B", "C", "D")), 
          timevar="time", times = c("a", "b", "c"))
}
```

Test performance:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(mydf), f2(mydf), f3(mydf), f4(mydf))
# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
#  f1(mydf) 463.006547 492.073086 528.533319 514.189548 538.910756 867.93356   100
#  f2(mydf)   3.737321   4.108376   6.674066   4.332391   4.761681  47.71142   100
#  f3(mydf)  60.211254  64.766770  86.812077  87.040087  92.841747 262.89409   100
#  f4(mydf)  40.596455  43.753431  61.006337  48.963145  69.983623 230.48449   100
```

Observations:

- Base R's `reshape` would not be able to handle reshaping "mydf2".
- The "dplyr" + "tidyr" approach would mangle the results in the resulting "varB", "varC", and "varD" because values would be coerced to character.
- As the benchmarks show, `reshape` gives reasonable performance.

<sub>***Note***: Because of the difference in time between posting my last answer and the differences in approach, I thought I would share this as a new answer.</sub>

Comment: Nice and detailed. Couldn't you incorporate new `melt` functionality on to `splitstackshape` for the syntactic sugar it provides? Or have you already? I remember discussing about this some time back.

Comment: @Arun, on my to-do list. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/ceded54b616bdc61cb0f).

Comment: Brilliant! Looking forward.

Answer (score 2):

`merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" handles this by utilizing the `sep = "var.stubs"` construct:

```
library(splitstackshape)
merged.stack(dadmom, var.stubs = c("inc", "name"), sep = "var.stubs")
#    famid .time_1   inc name
# 1:     1       d 30000 Bill
# 2:     1       m 15000 Bess
# 3:     2       d 22000  Art
# 4:     2       m 18000  Amy
# 5:     3       d 25000 Paul
# 6:     3       m 50000  Pat
```

Notice that since there is no real separator in the variables that are being stacked, we can just strip out the `var.stubs` from the names to create the "time" variables. Using `sep = "var.stubs"` is equivalent to doing `sep = "inc|name"`.

This works because ".time_1" is created by stripping out what is left after removing the "var.stubs" from the column names.