# Reshape multiple values at once

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, reshape2, tidyr

I have a long data set I would like to make wide and I'm curious if there is a way to do this all in one step using the reshape2 or tidyr packages in R.

The data frame `df` looks like this:

```
id  type    transactions    amount
20  income       20          100
20  expense      25          95
30  income       50          300
30  expense      45          250
```

I'd like to get to this:

```
id  income_transactions expense_transactions    income_amount   expense_amount
20       20                           25                 100             95
30       50                           45                 300             250
```

I know I can get part of the way there with reshape2 via for example:

```
dcast(df, id ~  type, value.var="transactions")
```

But is there a way to reshape the entire df in one shot addressing both the "transactions" and "amount" variables at once?  And ideally with new more appropriate column names?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In "reshape2", you can use `recast` (though in my experience, this isn't a widely known function).

```
library(reshape2)
recast(mydf, id ~ variable + type, id.var = c("id", "type"))
#   id transactions_expense transactions_income amount_expense amount_income
# 1 20                   25                  20             95           100
# 2 30                   45                  50            250           300
```

You can also use base R's `reshape`:

```
reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", idvar = "id", timevar = "type")
#   id transactions.income amount.income transactions.expense amount.expense
# 1 20                  20           100                   25             95
# 3 30                  50           300                   45            250
```

Or, you can `melt` and `dcast`, like this (here with "data.table"):

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
dcast.data.table(melt(as.data.table(mydf), id.vars = c("id", "type")), 
                 id ~ variable + type, value.var = "value")
#    id transactions_expense transactions_income amount_expense amount_income
# 1: 20                   25                  20             95           100
# 2: 30                   45                  50            250           300
```

In later versions of `dcast.data.table` from "data.table" (1.9.8) [you will be able to do this directly](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/739). If I understand correctly, what @Arun is trying to implement would be doing the reshaping without first having to `melt` the data, which is what happens presently with `recast`, which is essentially a wrapper for a `melt` + `dcast` sequence of operations.

---

And, for thoroughness, here's the `tidyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydf %>% 
  gather(var, val, transactions:amount) %>% 
  unite(var2, type, var) %>% 
  spread(var2, val)
#   id expense_amount expense_transactions income_amount income_transactions
# 1 20             95                   25           100                  20
# 2 30            250                   45           300                  50
```

Comment: This is a nice answer (Enlightened +  Nice answer badges on the way...), but not sure what we need all this mess with `tidyr`, `dplyr`, `data.table`, `reshape` etc. when there is such a simple way of doing it with base R

Comment: @DavidArenburg, speed at scale, really. I'm an old hardcore fan of `reshape`, but it would not be my first recommendation if someone is working with remotely large data.

Comment: Now that I'm looking into `reshape`s source code it looks like it's all about endless `for`/`apply` loops. It is pity it wasn't written in C/C++ as all base R function should be

Comment: `reshape()` is simple? All I have to say to that is "bahahahaha"

Comment: @hadley, I can't speak for David, but I didn't interpret his comment to mean that `reshape()` was simple, but rather implied that the `reshape()` approach here is actually reasonably straightforward.

Comment: In that case, the whole point of "mess"ing with tidyr, dplyr, data.table, reshape2 etc, is that they generalise better to new problems, which reshape() does not.

Answer (score 6):

With data.table v1.9.6+, we can cast multiple `value.var` columns simultaneously (and also use multiple aggregation functions in `fun.aggregate`). Please see `?dcast` for more and also the examples section.

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6+
dcast(dt, id ~ type, value.var=names(dt)[3:4])
#    id transactions_expense transactions_income amount_expense amount_income
# 1: 20                   25                  20             95           100
# 2: 30                   45                  50            250           300
```