# Trying to re-create a specific type of pivot table in R

Tags: r

So, I have a process that I currently use Excel for, and I want to find the most efficient way to do it in R.

My data take this shape:

```
ID <- c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3))
Source <- rep(c("A", "A", "B"), 2)
Total <- c(11, 13, 12, 25, 27, 26)
Actions <- c(3, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10)
df <- data.frame(ID, Source, Total, Actions)
df 
#   ID Source Total Actions
# 1  1      A    11       3
# 2  1      A    13       2
# 3  1      B    12       3
# 4  2      A    25       8
# 5  2      A    27       9
# 6  2      B    26      10
```

I run an aggregate on `Total` and `Actions`:

```
df2 <- aggregate(cbind(Total, Actions) ~ ID + Source, 
          data = df, FUN=sum)
df2
#   ID Source Total Actions
# 1  1      A    24       5
# 2  2      A    52      17
# 3  1      B    12       3
# 4  2      B    26      10
```

But what I really want is a situation where the totals for A and totals for B are separate columns in the same table. Currently I am doing it like this:

```
df2_A <- df2[(df2$Source == "A"), ]
df2_B <- df2[(df2$Source == "B"), ]
x <- merge(df2_A, df2_B, by.x = "ID", by.y = "ID")
x 
#   ID Source.x Total.x Actions.x Source.y Total.y Actions.y
# 1  1        A      24         5        B      12         3
# 2  2        A      52        17        B      26        10
```

My question is, is there a more elegant way to go from `df` to `x` in one step? I feel like what I am doing now is a crude hack, and I want to expand my R knowledge.

Comment: Related: [Reshape multiple values at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247078/reshape-multiple-values-at-once). "Just" add `fun = sum` to the `dcast` steps.

Comment: Thanks, Henrik, that thread is teaching me a lot also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to simplify the whole operation into a single pipe

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% group_by(ID, Source) %>% 
  summarize_all(sum) %>% ungroup()%>%
  gather(key, value, -c(ID, Source)) %>% 
  unite(newkey, key, Source) %>% 
  spread(newkey, value)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>      ID Actions_A Actions_B Total_A Total_B
#> * <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     1         5         3      24      12
#> 2     2        17        10      52      26
```

Comment: This is probably going to end up being the answer, but I'm curious if anyone sends anything else. Thanks!

Comment: There's also a `data.table` solution (which allows casting multiple columns at once without `unite` step), but I'll let other people answer.

Answer (score 1):

A `reshape2` version:

```
library(reshape2)

> dcast(melt(df, id.vars = ID), ID ~ Source + variable, fun.aggregate = sum)
  ID A_Total A_Actions B_Total B_Actions
1  1      24         5      12         3
2  2      52        17      26        10
```

And a kind of questionable base version, that gets you pretty close to the desired output, including appropriate source columns:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, f = ID), function(x) {
  y <- (split(x, Source))
  ID = x[[1]][1]
  cbind(ID, do.call(cbind, lapply(y, function(z) { 
    w <- data.frame(Source = z[1,2])
    q <- data.frame(t(colSums(z[,c("Total", "Actions")])))
    data.frame(w,q)
  })))
}))

  ID A.Source A.Total A.Actions B.Source B.Total B.Actions
1  1        A      24         5        B      12         3
2  2        A      52        17        B      26        10
```

Comment: Or using the `recast` wrapper: `recast(df, ID ~ Source + variable, id.var = c("ID", "Source"), fun = sum)`

Comment: @Henrik - Thanks for the catch, didn't know about that!

Answer (score 1):

OP is pretty close to solution. He has to just take another aggregate of over the `df2` and he would have got the answer.

In short `aggregate` of `aggregate` is an option to find solution as:

```
aggregate(cbind(Source,Total,Actions)~ID, 
  data=aggregate(cbind(Total, Actions) ~ ID + Source, data = df, FUN=sum), I)
#   ID Source.1 Source.2 Total.1 Total.2 Actions.1 Actions.2
# 1  1        1        2      24      12         5         3
# 2  2        1        2      52      26        17        10
```

Comment: @mmyoung77 Thanks for your comments. I appreciate your efforts to put details in the question.  BTW, it seems you have forgotten to mark/accept any of the available solutions.